# Checking if any class in an array is present on the current page and saving the matched class as a variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a plugin for a CMS that has lots of different templates. As part of the plugin I am pulling text from a specific description box on the page. The problem is that every template has a different class name for the description box. I have gotten the plugin to work on a specific template that uses ".class1" but I would like to make it work no matter what template its installed on.

I basically want to put the class names from each template in an array and then check and see which one is on the page. I then want to store the matched class name in a variable that I can use.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have any code examples to help with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop through an array of classes and check to see if there are any elements matching each class on the page. The matched class names get pushed into a new array.

```
var classes = [".abc", ".def", ".ghi"];
var found = [];

for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    if($(classes[i]).length > 0) {
        found.push(classes[i]);
    }
}
```

If you're certain that only one class in the initial list will be found, you can stop after your first hit:

```
var classes = [".abc", ".def", ".ghi"];
var found;

for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    if($(classes[i]).length > 0) {
        found = classes[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! I then want to get the text that is in the matched class. I was using class1.text(); before, but now I would like to use the matched class that is populated in the "found" variable. do you know how I would write this? found.text() does not work. Should I open up a new question altogether?

Comment: @ChrisS-E Since `found` is a string, you can pass it to jquery like `$(found). text()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.querySelector() to find the element with one of the classes.

Note that if you want to find more than one instance - document.querySelectorAll() will create a node list.As @Hydrothermal says - if there are multiple elements with that class - you will need to push them into an array and using an index [0] to identify them.

```js
var templates = ["first-template", "second-template", "third-template"];
var currentTemplate;

templates.forEach(function(template){
  let test = document.querySelector("." + template);
  if(test !== null) {currentTemplate = template};
})

console.log(currentTemplate); // gives secondTemplate
```

```html
<div class="second-template">I am a template</div>
```